# Multiple Elements in ElementMaker in lxml python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I wish to use ElementMaker in lxml to build an xml representation of an excel spreadsheet with the corresponding nesting. I would like

```
<excelbook>
  workbook info
  <excelsheet>
      <sheetname>Sheet1</sheetname>
      <exceltable>
        <numrows>10</numrows>
        <numcols>13</numcols>
      </exceltable>
      <exceltable>
        <numrows>10</numrows>
        <numcols>13</numcols>
      </exceltable>
    </excelsheet>
    <excelsheet>
      <sheetname>Sheet2</sheetname>
      <exceltable>
        <numrows>10</numrows>
        <numcols>13</numcols>
      </exceltable>
      <exceltable>
        <numrows>10</numrows>
        <numcols>13</numcols>
      </exceltable>
  </excelsheet>
</excelbook>
```

My python code looks like the following

```
    for excelSheet in excelBook.excelSheets:

        for excelTable in excelSheet.excelTables:

            exceltable = E.exceltable(
                E.num_rows(str(excelTable.num_rows)),   
                E.num_cols(str(excelTable.num_cols)),
                )

        excelsheet = E.excelsheet(
                exceltable,
                E.sheetname(excelSheet.sheetName),
                )

        excelbook = E.excelbook(
        excelsheet,
        E.bookname(fullpathname),
        E.numSheets(str(excelBook.numSheets))) 

        root = E.XML(excelbook)
```

The problem is that I can only nest one sheet inside each book and one table inside each sheet. How do I change the code to allow multiple sheets in each book and multiple tables inside each sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't next a tag with the same tag name twice under the same root and expect them to be appended one after another rather than the second one overriding the first one, because this is not very coherent.
For example if you have:

```
<root>
    <elem1>some text 1</elem1>
</root>
```

If you try to append another "elem1" tag to root, it will override the existing one.
I'd suggest you use indexing ("elem_0", "elem_1", "elem_2".. etc).